# What is the proper way to make an increment function work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, increment

I'm creating a website that let people read short stories in several chapters.
For this, I nested a chapter scaffold inside a novel scaffold, and linked (novel has_many :chapters, chapters belongs_to :novel) them both together.
However I'm trying to get the chapter's number inside the URL (instead of the id, which never decreases). Setting the chapter as is is not a problem, but I'd like to automate the chapter number without my users needing to add it themselves.

To do so, I figured that all I needed was to get how many chapter the current novel had by checking `self.class.where(:novel_id => @novel).count`. At this point, I have no issues, however it gets complicated when I try to increment this number, I get the error: `undefined method 'anoter_one' for 0:Fixnum`

Here is my "another_one" function inside my model (I tried some things)

```
  def another_one
    @number = self.class.where(:novel => @novel).count.to_i
    @number.increment
  end
```

Here is the controller

```
  def create
    @novel = Novel.find(params[:novel_id])
    @chapter = Chapter.new(chapter_params)
    @chapter.chapter_number.another_one
    @chapter.novel = @novel
    if @chapter.save
      redirect_to novel_chapter_path(@novel, @chapter), notice: 'Chapter was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your calling `anoter_one` - which is a misspelling of `another` on the value of `@chapter.chapter_number` - not the model.

One way to solve this is by using an [association callback](http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/12/01/functions-to-call-upon-activerecord-association-callbacks/):

```
class Novel
  has_many :chapters, before_add: :set_chapter_number
  def set_chapter_number(chapter)
    if chapter.chapter_number.blank? 
      chapter.chapter_number = self.chapters.size + 1
    end
  end
end
```

In order for the callback to be called properly you want to build the associated items off the parent:

```
def new
  @novel = Novel.find(params[:novel_id])
  @chapter = @novel.chapters.new
end

def create
  @novel = Novel.find(params[:novel_id])
  @chapter = @novel.chapters.new(chapter_params)

  if @chapter.save
    redirect_to [@novel, @chapter], notice: 'Chapter was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I adapted / pasted your code, but it doesn't work. The form gets submitted without issue but in the database, the :chapter_number doesn't get any new value. Was I suppose to keep my "another_one" (typoed, by the way) function ?